# Omit repeated values in mysql query so the json file has only one of each

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

This is the query part of my json.php which is the source file of my jquery ui autocomplete input

```
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

$qstring = "SELECT nombre as value FROM ingredientes WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$term."%'";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);//query the database for entries containing the term

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
{
    $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
    //$row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
    $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
```

The problem is that file my return result as:

```
[{"value":"one"},{"value":"one"},{"value":"ones"},{"value":"ona"}]
```

So the word will be suggested twice. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$qstring = "SELECT DISTINCT nombre as value 
    FROM ingredientes 
    WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$term."%'";
```

Or

```
$qstring = "SELECT nombre as value 
    FROM ingredientes 
    WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$term."%'
    GROUP BY nombre";
```

Do use `mysql_real_escape_string` though...

Comment: thanks! i know its not part of the question, but how can i order them by 'word-match' grade ?

Comment: Define 'word-match-grade' ? Something like `ORDER BY nombre = '$term' DESC, nombre LIKE '%$term' DESC, LENGHT(nombre) ASC, nombre ASC`?

Comment: is that supoused to work? it wont return results.. i mean to show the most similar words first (or is that job of the autocomplete feautre?)

Comment: OTOH, yes that is supposed to work, debug it, just did it without testing: order by (1) exact match, (2) start is the same, (3) shortest string that matches (4) rest alphabetically. If nothing is returned, we've introduced a syntax error somewhere, try to find out what that is (`echo mysql_error();`).

Comment: i do that mistake all the time, netbeans and similar should start detecting that one xD